# How to dynamically add and get total of time from database?

Tags: php, mysql, time

I'm trying to get the total time duration of all time variables from the database. But I don't seem to get the right total or result. This is my code...

```
    $len = count($mids);
    foreach($mids as $key => $val)
    {
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbltempmovies WHERE mid='".$val."'");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $dur += strtotime($row['duration']);
        }
    }
    $duration = date('g:i:s', $dur);
```

PS: I know I'm not using mysqli or PDO. I'll fix that once I'm done with this.

Comment: the expected result is more than 12 hours ?

Comment: This may be help you!!!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837435/php-addition-of-multiple-durations-to-get-total-duration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating total hours out of database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158810/calculating-total-hours-out-of-database)

Comment: GuRu it worked. thanks a lot :)

Comment: Note that [`TIME` data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) has a limit in MySQL, which is `838:59:59`. So make sure you don't exceed it with `SELECT SUM(duratation) FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$duration = date('g:i:s', strtotime($dur));
```

Comment: didn't work. it only made the result a default 12:00:00